# Create a pandas dataframe from a python dictionary. Python dictionary has multiple keys and its values have both string and list data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a program that generate multiple dictionaries at each iteration, that follows this format.

```
# dict1
{"key1": "abc", "key2": True, "key3": []}
# dict2
{"key1": "def", "key2": False, "key3": ["a", "b", "c"]}
...
```

I would like to add these to a pandas dataframe.

On first iteration I create a df,

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1, columns=dict1.keys(), index=["abc"])
```

On subsequent iterations I append to mdf,

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame(dict2, columns=dict2.keys(), index=["def"])
mydf = mydf.append(tdf)
```

This approach works when there are no list values in my dictionaries. If there are list values(such as key3) I get the following ValueError,

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (1)
```

Expected output,

```
    key1 key2 key3
abc  "abc"  True  []
def  "def"  False  ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Provided expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first load your dict to a Series and then convert it to a DataFrame, keep appending to a df list, finally use pd.concat to merge your DFs.

```
df_list = []
df_list.append(pd.Series(dict1).to_frame().T)
df_list.append(pd.Series(dict2).to_frame().T)
pd.concat(df_list).set_index('key1', drop=False).rename_axis('')


    key1    key2    key3
abc abc     True    []
def def     True    [a, b, c]
```

Comment: I've just updated my question, this approach wouldn't allow me to set my index labels. I would like my index label to be key1.

Comment: Cool, this works. Thanks a ton.
I'm getting started with pandas, while manipulating dataframes, do you believe Series is better option than Dictionaries?

Comment: No worries glad it helped. Please upvote if you found it helpful.